# Android Studio Helper Object

Tags: java, android, text, io

In my new app I wanted to make an IO object that will help me access text files written in a raw folder located in the res folder.
The object is a java class that is written in the same location as all of the rest java files.
The goal of this object is that I can access files from all of the activities instead of writing them again and again.
But when I tried to do that I stumbled upon a few errors that I can't find a way to fix them.
While writing the code:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(R.raw.fName);
```

(fName is a Sting that the action receives)

Android studio marked the "raw" red and said it didn't recognize it.
From what I understand the R file doesn't recognize the raw folder.
The second problem is , when I write the code:

```
 InputStream is = Context.this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.fName);
```

It still gives me an error at the raw and an error at "Context.this" , and asks me to split the deceleration or to surround it with a try block , which doesn't help. And at the headline there is a throws IOException so any errors with IO should be cleared.
And if there is an easier way to access actions in java files , a link or an explanation will help a lot.
P.S. a raw folder is a premade folder with premade text files , also an easier way to read and write in premade files will help.

Comment: Try to clean and re-build the project. If that doesn't help try to delete the generated R.java file and let Android studio regenerate it.

Comment: Even after I rebuild the project and I also copied the code to a different project on a different computer , but the second problem still stands.

Comment: So rebuilding fixed the `raw` issue, but you still getting an error for `Context.this` ? did you try modify it to  `this` ? (assuming this code is called within an activity class).

Comment: The code is called within an activity class and if I modify it to `this` it will give out an error.

Comment: Then post a full stacktrace of the error

Comment: there is no stack trace, the code itself gives out an error and doesn't let the app start